# Parenthesis and regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I am currently working on an exercise in which I need to locate all the occurring (),[],{}, both grouped or single, and I can't figure out the regular expression. I do not need the text in between. I already filtered them out of my string with this:

```
string_updated = string.gsub(/([a-zA-Z]|\d+)|\s+/, "")
```

For example. in this string:

```
"I can't ( find the } regular ] expression to ) grab these[."
```

All I want is: `(, }, ], ), [`.

Comment: The question is unclear…

Comment: `[()\[\]{}]+` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with `([\(\[\{]).*([\)\]\}])`

Here is a working example: http://regex101.com/r/qH1uF5

Comment: Not with `I can't ( find the } regular ] expression to ) grab these[. All I want is: (, }, ], ), [ .`

Comment: To avoid escaping noise, inside classes, only the `[` needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below regex:

`([][)(}{])`

Explanations:

```
(            # Start capturing group
  [          # Match any of these characters
    ][)(}{   # Desired chars
  ]          # End of char group
)            # End of capturing group
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/pF6gC4)

Comment: Its a trick, `]` is allowed unescaped as first char in a class, However, even classes are excluded in expanded mode, where it is now two classes as you post it.

Comment: Maybe Ruby is different. I don't know. Anyway this is compressed `[ # Match any of these characters\n ][)(}{ # Desired chars\n ]` which is now two classes.

Comment: @sln I didn't know it about ruby in new versions. But the regex works well in 1.8.7v: http://rubular.com/r/mzNF4GVtbw

Comment: The commented expanded regex you show is not the same as the regex listed at the top.

Comment: @sln I think u mistaken. that's just for line by line explanation not for using as the main pattern. however I don't think we can do commenting in another way?!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
a = "I can't ( find the } regular ] expression to ) grab these[."
brackets = %w|( ) [ ] { }|
puts a.scan(Regexp.union(brackets)).join(', ') #=> (, }, ], ), [
```